# Xamarin Launcher.OpenAsync "request url too long"

Tags: android, xamarin, url-scheme

I am trying to send an image (it can't be a file, must be a base64) to another app using the URI scheme and the [Xamarin Launcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/launcher?tabs=android).

```
var uri = new Uri(url);  
await Launcher.OpenAsync(uri); // await Launcher.OpenAsync(url);
```

Both: `new Uri(url)` and `await Launcher.OpenAsync(url)` give an exception if the url lenght is over 2000 characters.

As I know, passing base64 strings to other apps (for example to edit an image or print a document) is normal. So why does Xamarin limit it to 2000 characters?

Is there a workaround?

**Edit:**
Exception on `new Uri`:

```
System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long.
  at System.Uri.CreateThis (System.String uri, System.Boolean dontEscape, System.UriKind uriKind) [0x0007b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/System/net/System/UriExt.cs:55 
  at System.Uri..ctor (System.String uriString) [0x00014] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/System/net/System/URI.cs:408
```

Exception on `Launcher.OpenAsync`:

```
System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long.
  at System.Uri.CreateThis (System.String uri, System.Boolean dontEscape, System.UriKind uriKind) [0x0007b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/System/net/System/UriExt.cs:55 
  at System.Uri..ctor (System.String uriString) [0x00014] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/System/net/System/URI.cs:408 
  at Xamarin.Essentials.Launcher.OpenAsync (System.String uri) [0x00013] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Essentials\Launcher\Launcher.shared.cs:32
```

Comment: "passing base64 strings to other apps is normal" - it is?  I don't see anything in the source that appears to be a "Xamarin limit" as opposed to a native platform limit.  What is the **specific exception** that is being thrown?

Comment: I added the exceptions. Ok, Launcher.OpenAsync is just calling new Uri. So the exception is always on new Uri. As I know, Android is able to open schemes with up to 1MB. iOS is able to open url schemes with over 200MB of data. I just can't understand why I have this limit of only 2000 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is the limitation of System.Uri class. While it is not officially documented if you search you will find this being discussed on many places like here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/6435996c-4b96-4887-be60-f6e10120f0a0/long-http-get-requests-and-a-uri-max-length-constraint

Basically you have to use the native classes to achieve what you want.